# Laravel can't find php extension ssh2_connect()

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

I'm having some problems with my Laravel app. I'm trying to run function `ssh2_connect()`, but every time it returns:

> Call to undefined function App\Git\ssh2_connect()

I tried to run that function outside Laravel project in my `localhost /htdocs` folder, and it is working fine.
Any ideas how to solve that? By the way, every ssh library seams to have some problems on Laravel.

Here is the example:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('YOUR IP HERE', 22);
if( !ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'PASSWORD') ) {
  echo "Authorization failed !";
}
```

Comment: provide code please

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

The error message status that it cannot find the `ssh2_connect()` function in the current namespace, which indicates that the function doesn't exist in the global scope either.

The `ssh2_*` functions needs to be [installed as an extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php) in your PHP environment.